# Capture email address with substitute characters or patterns

Tags: regex, ruby

I have user posts that I need to try to remove email addresses from. People have been trying to get around my simple regex,so I am trying to find a solution to it. Any help modifying the below would be helpful.

https://rubular.com/r/B2rzST2u39fjDm

The pattern would be

```
a word made of any of these characters: [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]
followed by an @ sign, or the word "At" or " at " in lower case or upper case, surrounded by 0-4 spaces.
followed by another word of these characters ([a-z0-9]
followed by a "." or "dot", " Dot ", "D0T" in lower case or upper case, surrounded by 0-4 spaces.
followed by any 2-3 of these characters [a-z]
```

RegEx should be case insensitive.

My regex is missing some of the items, specifically a domain with a prefix.

Comment: You have repeating capturing groups which I think is not needed. You can optionally repeat the `(?:\.|dot)` part after the `@`. Perhaps like this ``[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~\-]+\s{0,4}(?:@|at)+\s{0,4}[a-z0-9]+\s{0,4}(?:(?:\.|dot)[a-z0-9]+\s{0,4})*(?:\.|dot)\s{0,4}[a-z]{2,3}`` https://regex101.com/r/KlcB9Z/1 or https://rubular.com/r/rXl0Ae4sZxgkdi

Comment: I'd be surprised if you find a way that people cannot bypass.

Comment: Note you do not need `m` flag in Rubular, it enables `.` outside a character class to match any char including line breaks. It is not the same `m` as at regex101.com. I think @Thefourthbird's solution works for all your cases.

Comment: What does the ? part do in the capture? e.g. (?:@|at) or (?:\.|dot)?

Comment: It matches either @ or `at` and either `.` or `dot`

Comment: I just found my solution `?:` does not do the capture of the group. :) Thanks fourth bird for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the requirements, one option could be adding a repeating group before the last part.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~\-]+\s{0,4}(?:@|at)\s{0,4}[a-z0-9]+\s{0,4}(?:(?:\.|dot)[a-z0-9]+\s{0,4})*(?:\.|dot)\s{0,4}[a-z]{2,3}
```

The parts will match:

- `` [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~\-]+ `` Repeat 1+ times what is listed
- `\s{0,4}` Match 0-4 whitespace chars
- `(?:@|at)` Either match `@` or `at`
- `\s{0,4}` Match 0-4 whitespace chars
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times a char in the ranges a-z or 0-9
- `\s{0,4}` Match 0-4 whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\.|dot)[a-z0-9]+\s{0,4}`
- `)*` Close Group and repeat it 0+ times
- `(?:\.|dot)` Match either `.` or `dot`
- `\s{0,4}[a-z]{2,3}` Match 0-4 whitespace chars and 2 or 3 times a char in the range a-z

[Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/6PAPgwgrKgfMwP) (And as @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) pointed out, you don't need the `m` modifier)

Comment: One area it does not work is Name@prefix dot domain.com. I assume this would work:  (?:\.|dot)\s{0,4}[a-z0-9]+\s{0,4}

Comment: @Lefty Yes, you could add optional whitespace chars after the first `(?:\.|dot)` https://rubular.com/r/kBCUJhY3aMXRX1